# How to ask for a given choice of options?

Tags: translation, grammar

In English one way to ask which option is the right one is by using whether:

**Could you tell me, whether you are a student, teacher or visitor?**

How would this be realized in Chinese?

Comment: 你能告诉我，你是学生，老师或访客？

Comment: here is how the version in above comment was generated：feeding  ＂Could you tell me, whether you are a student, teacher or visitor ?＂ to iciba翻译 which has become baidu翻译 results in 
你能告诉我，不管你是学生，老师或访客？Of course users immediately recognize that there should be no 不管 （which might correspond to ＂whether you are 。。。 （just） tell me＂），some reading experience also would suggest 还是 instead of 或。

Comment: I am just wondering if a 是否 would fit in there: 你能告诉我**是否**你是学生、老师或者访客？[waiting for a native speaker's point of view]

Comment: see iciba， 是否 whether （or not，yes or no）is followed by just one option，

Answer (score 3, accepted):

请问，您是学生，老师，还是来参观的？

请问 = May I ask

Comment: You could add  一下， 请问一下，

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer would be "A，B还是C？"